# How Can I link button with keyboard in C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, forms, button, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to link button in Window Form with letter "S" in Keyboard.
For Example:
If I press "Button1" the key "S" will pressed automatically

Comment: Note that if you click a button, then that button will have the focus and so the keypress will (generally) be directed to the button. However, you could do `SendKeys.Send("S");` in response to the button press.

Comment: No dude, I just want to press "Button1" in Windows Form and the letter "S" in keyboard automatically pressed .

Answer (score 2):

More on this at [MSDN article for the `SendKeys` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
// Clicking Button1
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("S");
}
```